# SMTP and PHP problem

Tags: php, email, smtp, localhost

I have setup WAMP for Windows 64-bit and am trying to use the `mail()` function
to send an email from my local host to another mail server (for example, Gmail or Hotmail).

The problem is in PHP and SMTP connection. I get the following error message:

> Verify your smtp and port 25.

Can anyone tell me what is causing this error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When using mail(), PHP expects to find a mailserver running on localhost. You probably don't have that. You can try using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/phpmailer) instead.

The configuration would then look something like this:

```
<?php
 require("class.phpmailer.php");

 $mail = new PHPMailer();

 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
 $mail->Username = 'user';
 $mail->Password = 'pass';

 $mail->From = 'john.doe@example.com';
 $mail->FromName = "John Doe";
 $mail->AddAddress('test@gmail.com');

 $mail->Subject = 'test subject';
 $mail->Body = 'Works?';

 $mail->Send()
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I understand my problem have you any smtp programme to propose me for localhost smtp?